# Rotating a vector using Matrix.rotateM

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix-multiplication

I have made a simple class called Vector3.
It's a 3 dimensional vector with some basic math implementions.
Now i want to be able to rotate this single vector, but i get an exception.

I have this:

```
private static final float[] matrix = new float[16];
private static final float[] inVec = new float[4];
private static final float[] outVec = new float[4];  

public Vector3 rotate(float angle, float axisX, float axisY, float axisZ)
{
    inVec[0] = x;
    inVec[1] = y;
    inVec[2] = z;
    inVec[3] = 1;

    Matrix.setIdentityM(matrix, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, angle, axisX, axisY, axisZ);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(outVec, 0, matrix, 0, inVec, 0);
    x = outVec[0];
    y = outVec[1];
    z = outVec[2];
    return this;
}
```

And i call i by making this:

```
Vector3 v = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    v.rotate(90f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
```

What i get is an IllegalArgumentException at:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(outVec, 0, matrix, 0, inVec, 0);
```

It says that

> length - offset < n

Does anyone have a clue about what i am doing wrong?

*I didn't wrote this Vector3 function from the beginning, it's borrowed from the book "beggining android games"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using multiplyMM method that mutiplies 2 matrices and return a matrix instead of using multiplyMV (MV stands for matrix-vector) that multiplies your rotation matrix with your vector, returning the rotated vector.