# specific rotation of png images in Android

Tags: android, rotation, png

I have one png image.

[image: original image]

Then, I want to flip this triangle as on the next image.

[image]

Red region it is our original image which is reflected and turned. And then I want to rotate new region (red region) on different angles.
How can i do it in android?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rotate an image in android you should look here

- [Rotate image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389613/rotate-image-in-android)

Or here

- [Android: Rotate image in imageview by an angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle)

To get a mirror image of your PNG, do this (taken from the link below, from Dalmas's answer)

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f); 
Bitmap mirroredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.width(), bmp.height(),  matrix, false);
```

- [How to mirror an image file? (2.2+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552298/how-to-mirror-an-image-file-2-2)

To rotate a vector look here

- [Rotating a vector using Matrix.rotateM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073419/rotating-a-vector-using-matrix-rotatem)

Comment: Everything is good... but... I think I'll have a little problem with straightforwardness of lines... as You can see border between green and red region is not ideal line... because it is pixels png image... and when I rotate image i'll take line of transperent regions insead of border

Comment: maybe, i can use vector graphic in this case? but i don't know how do it correctly

Comment: Thanks :) Maybe, it will help me!